# Updating content on click of icon

Tags: angular, angular8, angular9, angular10

I am working on an angular application. My code is as follows

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-card-example-lritas?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

In my code I have a image on click of which I can edit the title. Problem I facing is when I click on that icon cursor automatically doesn't show in input field until and unless I go and manually click on input. And second problem I am facing in this is If I click on input box and delete my default title and move away then only image is left. I want if user does not add any title then and leave then again same default title should be displayed. How can I do that?

Comment: Howdy, welcome to SO! Have you tried anything yet? [Setting focus to an input](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-1-d&q=angular+set+focus+to+input) and [working with input values](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-1-d&q=angular+set+input+value) are a pretty common thing with lots of examples out there. Is there a particular part you're stuck on?

Answer (score 0):

```
import { Component, ElementRef, OnDestroy, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject, Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { takeUntil } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  name = 'Angular 6';
  public title = 'Click here to edit title';
  editing$ = new BehaviorSubject(false);
  destroyed$ = new Subject<void>();

  @ViewChild('input') inputEl: ElementRef;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.editing$.pipe(takeUntil(this.destroyed$)).subscribe(() => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        if (this.inputEl) {
          this.inputEl.nativeElement.focus();
        }
      });
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.destroyed$.next();
    this.destroyed$.complete();
  }
}
```

```
Start editing to see some magic happen :)
<mat-divider></mat-divider>
<mat-card class="example-card">
  <span *ngIf="!(editing$ | async)">{{ title === '' ? 'Click here to edit title' : title }}</span>
  <input #input class="title-input" *ngIf="editing$ | async" [(ngModel)]="title" (blur)="editing$.next(false)">
  <svg
    style="margin-left: 0.5rem"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    width="16"
    height="16"
    viewBox="0 0 24 24"
    (click)="editing$.next(true)"
  >
    <path d="M7.127 22.562l-7.127 1.438 1.438-7.128 5.689 5.69zm1.414-1.414l11.228-11.225-5.69-5.692-11.227 11.227 5.689 5.69zm9.768-21.148l-2.816 2.817 5.691 5.691 2.816-2.819-5.691-5.689z"/>
  </svg>
</mat-card>
```